# Adding photos to magento ecommerce site

Tags: magento-1.4, magento

I have recently been assigned the project of reviving our old magento site, which is for a bookstore, version 1.4.1.1.  The first order of business that I need to do is to update the inventory on the site, which has about 95,000 items.  What is the best way to do this?  My inventory is all in a mysql database currently.
Secondly, I need to upload pictures for all of the entries, is there a way/ place that I can specify a base url for the picture, and then just add the specific location (ie bookpic.isbn.gif where the isbn will change based on the isbn of the book)?
I saw a previous post from over a year ago that listed good reference sites, where can I go for updated information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look on cutesave for an easy implementation and import for simple-products:
https://github.com/magento-hackathon/cutesave

https://github.com/magento-hackathon/cutesave/wiki/Cutesave-Tests

Good luck

Comment: Thanks, I have used this a few times now and it saves me a big chunk of time.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I've used is a [dataflow](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/introduction-to-magento-dataflow/) profile (Admin->System->Import/Export) to import products from a flat file. I exported the products from another database to a flat file, then used dataflow to import all products.

I [referenced an article](http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/how-to-import-product-images-from-external-url-in-magento/) that talked about modifying the profile to add an extra step to the import process where it downloads the image from a supplied URL in the flat file and saves it to the media/import directory before it attempts to check the media/import directory to import an image for the product.